# add attributes to large array of objects without going through every object manually

Tags: javascript, json

```
export const Schools = [
  {
    value: "Alabama A & M University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama at Birmingham"
  },
  {
    value: "Amridge University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama in Huntsville"
  },
  {
    value: "Alabama State University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama System Office"
  },
  {
    value: "The University of Alabama"
  }, +7000 more schools ]
```

I need each one of these to have a key and a field called text.
text should be equal to value, and keys should be unique.

How can I do this without actually going through 7000 schools manually in the file with my data?

ex:

```
 {
    value: "University of Alabama in Huntsville",
    text: "University of Alabama in Huntsville",
    key: 9,
  },
```

Comment: I think theres no actuall way of duing this, but to iterate over it. You should maybe have this values in a DB.

Comment: so i would need to use map and then update every object by giving it a key of the index its at and then adding the text attribute and just setting that equal to value?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new array by applying map operator on the old array after importing it

```js
var Schools = [{
    value: "Alabama A & M University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama at Birmingham"
  },
  {
    value: "Amridge University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama in Huntsville"
  },
  {
    value: "Alabama State University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama System Office"
  },
  {
    value: "The University of Alabama"
  }
]
var newVals = Schools.map(function(item, index) {

  return {
    value: item.value,
    text: item.value,
    key: index,
  }
});

console.log(newVals)
```

Comment: This works assuming that the key he needs is just the index in the array

Comment: Yes that the assumption but you can add your predefined value instead of index

Comment: Then again, this is going through 7000 schools

Comment: Well like you said theres no other way @GerardoBLANCO

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO that is right actually in terms of scalability performing this operation on server side will be better but i guess the SO wants to do it on the browser side ,may be that is the reason he tagged it with js(unless he is using nodejs)

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO an alternative can be the delegate this task to web worker so main thread will not be blocked.The worker can return the new array

Answer (score 0):

You ought to store the data differently if you want to alter the values in O(1) time. This is based on what you originally said in editing solely one, but the guy above has the right answer if you want to edit each object.

As so:

```
{
  university_1: { },
  university_2: { },
...
}
```

Then when you do:

```
obj.university_1.key = something_unique;
obj.university_1.text = some_value;
```

This can happen without any looping through, but you would need to create the data to look as I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 you can do it like:

```js
var Schools=[{value:"Alabama A & M University"},{value:"University of Alabama at Birmingham"},{value:"Amridge University"},{value:"University of Alabama in Huntsville"},{value:"Alabama State University"},{value:"University of Alabama System Office"},{value:"The University of Alabama"}];

const newArray = Schools.map((o,i) => Object.assign(o, {text: o.value, index: i+1}));
console.log( newArray )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Array map() with ES6 Arrow assignment :

```js
var schoolData = [{
    value: "Alabama A & M University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama at Birmingham"
  },
  {
    value: "Amridge University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama in Huntsville"
  },
  {
    value: "Alabama State University"
  },
  {
    value: "University of Alabama System Office"
  },
  {
    value: "The University of Alabama"
  }];
  
  var result = schoolData.map(obj => Object.assign(obj, {text: obj.value, index: schoolData.indexOf(obj)}));
  
  console.log(result);
```